# Core Data attempt to recursively call -save

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to save my core data context after deleting some data sent to the server-side. I'm getting this error when I try context.save()

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=132001 "(null)" UserInfo={message=attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted, stack trace=(
    0   CoreData                            0x0000000185e8b22c <redacted> + 156
    1   ???                                 0x0000000106b0caec 0x0 + 4407216876
    2   ???                                 0x0000000106b0cbd0 0x0 + 4407217104
    3   Bakery                              0x0000000100d64868 main + 0
    4   Bakery                              0x0000000100d601b0 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 48
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001020352cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010203528c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102046b58 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1016
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001020466f4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 136
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001832eb06c _pthread_wqthread + 1268
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001832eab6c start_wqthread + 4
)}
```

- The call:

  func sendBenefitsIfNeeeded(_ status: Reachability.Connection) {

  ```
  let hasInternetConnection = status != .none

  if hasInternetConnection {
          self.syncBenefits { _ in
              self.deleteBenefitsAlreadySynced()
          }

  } }
  ```
- Error here on context.save()

  private func syncBenefits(completion: @escaping (AppError?) -> Void) {
          syncEmployees { _ in
              let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BenefitEntity")

  ```
      request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      do {
          let result = try self.context.fetch(request)

          guard let resultArray = result as? [NSManagedObject] else {
              return
          }

          for data in resultArray {
              let registration = (data.value(forKey: "registration") as? Int) ?? 0

              self.grantBenefit(employeeRegistration: registration) { error, message in
                  guard let benefitSended = self.fetchBenefit(byRegistration: registration) else {
                      return
                  }

                  benefitSended.synced = true

                  DispatchQueue.main.async { 

                      do {
                          try self.context.save() // ERROR HERE!
                      } catch {

                      }
                      completion(error)
                  }
              }
          }
      } catch {
          print("Failed")
      }
  }
  ```

  }

I don't have any clue what is happening :(

PS: the syncBenefits is being called by a listener that calls the function when the internet connections is changed.

**#EDIT:** I tried with DispatchQueue.main.async (main thread) but the same error occurs :(

Comment: try to call it in Main thread.

Comment: I tried with DispatchQueue.main.async . same error :(

Comment: Why call save() for every object you update instead of after the loop?

Comment: That was a bad implementation, I admit... I've just change it to save after the loop. but the error persists :/